# react native expo building javascript bundle multiple times and fail

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm currently developing react native app and kinda new to it. Sometimes when I open my app in expo(usually using my iPhone device to debug app) it building javascript bundle multiple times very rapidly and it's unavailable to open app in my phone while the expo bundler is keep building javascript.

Indeed I need to force server to stop and restart, sometimes it works but not always.

It's not a big issue since I restart the app It's okay but why is this happening?

[image][image]

this is my screenshot of building javascript in expo. green one is from terminal and white one is from expo...